# execute method is always set to true

Tags: php, pdo, execute

I have a problem with a php script.

I want to delete a record from my database so I used the `execute()` method, and it should return false when there is no record with the code I pass as an argument, but it always return true despite of there is not any record with that code.

This is the script:

```
<?php

include('connexion.php');

//Récuperation des valeurs 
$code = $_POST['code'];

if($code)
{
    //Suppression de l'enregistrment avec le code = $code à m'aide d'une requête préparée
    $req = $bdd->prepare('Delete from chambre where code_ch = ?');
    $rowDeleted = $req->execute(array($code));
    //Ou bien : mysql_query('Delete from chambre where code_ch = '.$code);

    $supprimer = ($rowDeleted == true) ? 'OK' : 'notfound';

}
else
{
    $supprimer = 'empty';
}

header('Location: supprimer.php?supprimer='.$supprimer.'&code='.$code);

?>
```

Comment: Who told you it should return false if no rows were deleted? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php Also this worth checking: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PHP PDO object will (correctly) return a success/true value for deletion on ZERO rows. One way around this is to use something like `$pdo->rowCount()` to see how many rows the PDO affected. If you are trying to remove rows, you should consider a result of 0 from `$pdo->rowCount()` to mean that you did not successfully delete the row you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably confused. The documentation for execute says:

```
Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
```

It doesn't say anything about whether a row was deleted or not. You probably want [affected rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) if you want the number of rows deleted. However even then it's possibly a bad idea to depend on that. e.g what if two calls to delete the same row happen at the same time?

You shouldn't care that delete has actually deleted a row, only that the row you were trying to delete is no longer there.